Compute an $\varepsilon$ smaller than a certain minimal distance of $n$ real numbers.
Given $n$ positive real numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R_{>0}$, we want to compute an $\varepsilon>0$ in polynomial time such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in I_1} a_i \neq \sum_{i\in I_2} a_i \implies 
\left|\sum_{i\in I_1} a_i - \sum_{i\in I_2} a_i \right| \geq \varepsilon
\end{align}
holds for any two subsets $I_1,I_2 \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Or, in other words, we want it to fulfill
\begin{align}
\varepsilon \leq \min \left\{ {\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_ia_i} \colon
{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_ia_i} > 0,\, \sigma_i \in \{1,0,-1 \} \right\}.
\end{align}
This is an open question which I found on a bulletin board at my Uni, and I'm intruigued.
Clearly this is doable if the numbers $a_i=\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ are all rational, as then $\varepsilon := \frac{1}{q_1\cdot\cdot\cdot q_n}$ fulfills this, but in
general I have no idea—I tried to use Hurwitz's theorem to approximate the $a_i$ but that led nowhere.
The problem has some resemblence to the NP-complete Subset-Sum from complexity theory, but since this problem is not related to a decision problem, I would not expect it to be NP-hard.
It seems that if you just choose $\varepsilon$ really small, the statement should hold, I just don't know how to do that.
